# How to fix htaccess with queries and redirect

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /shop.php?page=$1 [L]
```

That works mostly, but if I have a page for example: shop.php?page=home&search=foo then the search=foo is ignored.

Can anyone please explain what is going on?

Comment: You need to use `QSA` for Query String Append (so in your case `[L,QSA]`. See [this Q for syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104868/htaccess-appending-to-query-string-with-qsa-without-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /shop.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This answer does nothing to explain what the problem is to the OP. Code only answers are not a good fit for Smack Overflow.